# Vue stored valued through props not being reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-reactivity, vue-props

So I pass value using [props] and stored it in child component's data. However, when passing [props] value changes from parent, it's not updating in child component's data. Is there a fix for this..?

[**Here is the link to w3 test**](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHND7XW9ANLU) (I tried to clarify the problem as much as possible here)

```
<div id='app'>
    <div id='parent'>
        <button @click='current_value()'>Click to see parent value</button>
        <br><br>
        <button @click='change_value($event)'>{{ txt }}</button>
        <br><br>
        <child-comp :test-prop='passing_data'></child-comp>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <center><code>As you can see, this methods is <b>NOT</b> reactive!</code></center>
</div>
<script>

new Vue({
    el: "#parent",
    data: {
        passing_data: 'Value',
        txt: 'Click to change value'
    },
    methods: {
        current_value(){
            alert(this.passing_data);   
        },
        change_value(e){
            this.passing_data = 'New Vaule!!';
            this.txt = 'Now click above button again to see new value';
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            e.target.style.color = 'white';
        }
    },
    components: {
        "child-comp": {
            template: `
                <button @click='test()'>Click here to see child (stored) value</button>
            `,
            props: ['test-prop'],
            data(){
                return {
                    stored_data: this.testProp
                }
            },
            methods: {
                test(){
                    alert(this.stored_data);
                }
            },
            watch: {
                stored_data(){
                    this.stored_data = this.testProp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Props have one way data flow, that's why it doesn't react when you update it from the parent component.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) Define a clone of your prop at data to make it reactive, and then you can change the value within the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you don't need `stored_data`. Use `alert(this.testProp)` directly.

Long answer: when child component is created, `stored_data` get it's value from `this.testProp`. But `data` is local, it won't change automatically. That's why you need to watch `testProp` and set it again. But is not working because of a simple mistake, your `watch` should be:

```js
            watch: {
                testProp(){ // here was the mistake
                    this.stored_data = this.testProp;
                }
            }
```